# Can I ask Allah for a religious wife but who has high libido?

Tags: nikah, sex, husband-wife, love

Assalamualaikum brothers and sisters

I'm 20 years old

I have a high libido and unable to control myself from watching bad video's and masturbate I'm trying to quit this for my future wife and to become a good Muslim

Alhamdulillah I'm clean for 3 days in this blessed month of Ramazan is helping me

When I get married I want to love my wife very much both physically and mentally

I want a wife who is somewhat shy but not much

Since I have a high libido I want a wife who has same interest and high libido like me. Like both our sex drive to be equal

I have so many things and fetishes that I want to do with my wife

Not anything Haram though

Can I ask Allah for a wife who is good in deen and also has interest in sex life

Am I a sinner to ask this?

Jazakallah

Comment: Yes, you can brother.

Comment: Watching bad movies will effect in your future life my bro. if you don't leave this work from now, it is possible that you do it in future even after your marriage. so your wife will be so sad if she findout that you masturbate...

Comment: don't you know that youth not married should fast? there is hadith. that mean fasting like all year round with some interruptions.

Answer (score 0):

my opinion only brother. stop wishing for those things. ask for a better wife. the one who would empower you and make you a better person. i am 23. and also had many fantasies. and also searching for a wife. im ny opinion, filthy sexual life is a sign of desires taking over you. take care brother.

Comment: But why can't he wish for those things as he already said that 'Not anything Haram though'.?

Comment: Ask for a wife who's heart is attached to Allah..

Answer (score 0):

Non-married guy thinking about future relationships are not conscious of Allah.
Person performs sin by his heart, if his heart is pure he stops performing sins. Firstly you should clear your heart from sexual thoughts. If you always think about future relationship with your wife, you never stop sins. You must make dua to stop dirty jobs and make dua to clean your heart from sins.